# POSTGRESQL: Insert Data from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image: Customer table]

In above table customer ids are listed what I want to do is to get those ids from this table,

create another table named PROMOTION CLASSES where PREMIUM, PLUS AND NORMAL are in columns and put first 100 ids under PREMIUM COLUMN and soon.

Please help.

Comment: Your table has no "PREMIUM" column or value, which makes your question unclear.

Comment: lot of confusion in your question, your "create table" is syntactically incorrect and does not relate to your table in image

Comment: @GMB I am making a list of customers listed under customer_id  in order to give them promotional benefits. THIS table of mine promotion_classes contains 3 integer columns namely PREMIUM , PLUS AND NORMAL where customer_id of first 100 people are listed under PREMIUM, 100-200 in Plus and so-on.

Comment: @SagarGupta . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  What do *you* mean by "first"?  And where does the 301st customer go?

Answer (score 0):

This creates you table with classification

```
CREATE TABLE promotion_classes as
    SELECT customer_id, 
        case when customer_id < 100 then
           'PREMIUM'
        else
           'NORMAL'
        END as CLASSES
    FROM CUSTOMER_TBL
```